# Print numbers in same place

Tags: c#

This code:

```cs
for (double i = -1; i < 1; i+=0.5)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"foo: {i:n5} | bar: {i:n5}");
}
```

Is printing this:

```
foo: -1.00000 | bar: -1.00000
foo: -0.50000 | bar: -0.50000
foo: 0.00000 | bar:  0.00000
foo: 0.50000 | bar:  0.50000
```

I don't like that there is a difference in position of numbers.

What I want to achieve is:

```
foo: -1.00000 | bar: -1.00000
foo: -0.50000 | bar: -0.50000
foo:  0.00000 | bar:  0.00000
foo:  0.50000 | bar:  0.50000
```

This seems to be much more readable. Is there any fast and simple way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
for (double i = -1; i < 1; i += 0.5)
  {
      //Console.WriteLine($"foo: {i:n5} | bar: {i:n5}");
      var s =string.Format("foo: {0,8:n5} | bar: {0,8:n5}", i);
      Console.WriteLine(s);
  }
```